# How do I make a simple plot using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, plot, graph

I am trying to plot a text files with X,Y values(attached inline). I am first converting the text file into 2 array objects XAxis1 and YAxis1. The plot doesn't come out properly. Unable to set the X and Y axis values.

Any help is much appreciated.

(Sample1.txt)XAxis1 : 0.51,0.52,0.53,0.54,0.55,0.56,0.57,0.58,0.59,0.6,0.61,0.62,0.63,0.64,0.65,0.66,0.67,0.68,0.69,0.7
(Sample2.txt)YAxis1:
29.63,30.03,30.94,31.67,33.59,35.09,35.35,35.04,36.71,36.77,36.84,37.45,33.87,31.68,30.98,27.97,29.24,38.52,33.37,27.8

Sorry could not paste the code, some errors..

Answer (score 0):

Some people have downvoted your question, because a google search can solve much bigger problems and this is not very exotic.

See https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot


ax_x = [
0.51,0.52,0.53,0.54,0.55,0.56,0.57,0.58,0.59,0.6,0.61,0.62,0.63,0.64,0.65,0.66,0.67,0.68,0.69,0.7]
ax_y = [
29.63,30.03,30.94,31.67,33.59,35.09,35.35,35.04,36.71,36.77,36.84,37.45,33.87,31.68,30.98,27.97,29.24,38.52,33.37,27.8]

plot(ax_x, ax_y)
```

In case reading from file is a problem, I recommend saving everything in a useful format.

See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json